# Javascript Listeners, are they held in memory?

Tags: php, ajax, events, browser, listener

I am building what I believe to be quite a large web application that uses Ajax calls and multiple "panes" within one html front-end.

The application will most likely run without a hitch on desktops but the app is also a paid service to be used on iPad.

My question is in regards to the way browsers use event listeners, since i use quite a large amount of them. Does the browser hold all of these in memory or just look for them as they are called?

Comment: They are held "in memory" somewhere. However, browsers (even on mobile devices) can cope with "more than you'll [likely] need" amount of handlers, as in **it's not your problem** [yet]. To reduce handlers, see approaches like `jQuery.on` with "deferred events" which can reduce the number of event handlers required (with event bubbling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of the JavaScript engine of each browser for example V8 can support up 512mb on 32-bit systems, and 1gb on 64-bit systems.

You can check for other browser, but to reach that amount with callbacks it's almost impossible or if you do you can probably find some way to optimize your application!

So i wouldn't worry about this issue if i were you

By the way the iPad JavaScript engine on Safari is Nitro which is way better than the one that runs over IE9 so if your app is running well on IE9 you will be fine on iPad!

http://javascript.crockford.com/performance.html

Comment: `(smaller is better)` er... the graph is the _opposite_ of what you want to show, is it not?

Comment: Yes it's use to be true with ie9 but they made some improvements since as well